# Decoding JSON into Codable Objects - with condition

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsobject, codable

I would like to decode JSON into Objects with Codable protocol.

The outcome that I want to achieve is:

```
[
 [ Collection
    < collectionType = item
    < collectionName = some name`
    < data = [ Item
                 < itemTitle = title
                 < itemSubtitle = subtitle,
               Item
                 < itemTitle = title
                 < itemSubtitle = subtitle ],
[ Collection
    < collectionType = location
    < collectionName = some name`
    < data = [ Location
                 < locationName = someName,
               Location
                 < locationName = someName ],
[ Collection
    < collectionType = item
    < collectionName = some name`
    < data = [ Item
                 < itemTitle = title
                 < itemSubtitle = subtitle,
               Item
                 < itemTitle = title
                 < itemSubtitle = subtitle ],
[ Collection
    < collectionType = location
    < collectionName = some name`
    < data = [ Location
                 < locationName = someName,
               Location
                 < locationName = someName ]]
```

The JSON is as follows:

```
    [{
        "collectionType": "item",
        "collectionName": "some name",
        "data": [
            {
                "itemTitle": "title",
                "itemSubtitle": "subtitle",
            },
            {
                "itemTitle": "title",
                "itemSubtitle": "subtitle",
            }
         ]
      },
      {
        "collectionType": "location",
        "collectionName": "some name",
        "data": [
            {
                "locationName": "a name",
            },
            {
                "locationName": "a name",
            }
         ]
      },
      {
        "collectionType": "item",
        "collectionName": "some name",
        "data": [
            {
                "itemTitle": "title",
                "itemSubtitle": "subtitle",
            },
            {
                "itemTitle": "title",
                "itemSubtitle": "subtitle",
            }
         ]
      },
      {
        "collectionType": "location",
        "collectionName": "some name",
        "data": [
            {
                "locationName": "a name",
            },
            {
                "locationName": "a name",
            }
         ]
      }
  ]
```

As you can see the Collection will be of type item or location. And the data will be according to that type. 
How should I achieve that with Codable?

My objects are as follows:

```
class Collection: NSObject, Codable {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let collectionType: String
    let collectionName: String
    let data????

    // MARK: - Keyes

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case collectionType
        case collectionName
    }
}

class Item: NSObject, Codable {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let itemTitle: String
    let itemSubtitle: String

    // MARK: - Keyes

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case itemTitle
        case itemSubtitle
    }
}

class Location: NSObject, Codable {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let locationName: String

    // MARK: - Keyes

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case locationName
    }
}
```

**How can I propagate data with the appropriate objects?**

Comment: Is my enum based solution (Approach 2 below) suitable? I believe it solves the problem in a flexible, convenient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest two approaches:

#### Approach 1

Change your data structure to remove the ambiguity of whether `data` describes an item or a location:

```
[{
    "collectionName": "some name",
    "items": [
        {
            "itemTitle": "title",
            "itemSubtitle": "subtitle",
        },
        {
            "itemTitle": "title",
            "itemSubtitle": "subtitle",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "collectionName": "some name",
    "locations": [
        {
            "locationName": "a name",
        },
        {
            "locationName": "another name",
        }
    ]
}]
```

... and modify your `Collection` to have an optional `locations` and optional `items`.

#### Approach 2

If changing your JSON structure is not an option, then I suggest changing your `Collection` class to:

```
class Collection: Codable {
    let collectionType: String
    let collectionName: String
    let data: [CollectionData]
}
```

... and creating an enum `CollectionData`:

```
enum CollectionError: Error {
    case invalidData
}

enum CollectionData {
    case item(Item)
    case location(Location)
}

extension CollectionData: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let item = try? Item(from: decoder) {
            self = .item(item)
            return
        }

        if let location = try? Location(from: decoder) {
            self = .location(location)
            return
        }

        throw CollectionError.invalidData
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        switch self {
        case .item(let item):
            try item.encode(to: encoder)
        case .location(let location):
            try location.encode(to: encoder)
        }
    }
}
```

Pros and cons of the two approaches:

### Approach 1

Pro: Makes the data more self-descriptive

Con: Allows a collection with neither `items` nor `locations`

### Approach 2

Pro: Works with existing data structure

Con: Would allow a `data` array that was partly `Location` and partly `Item`

Unless there's more to your real code, you seem to be defining `CodingKeys` exactly as the default would be, so you can probably remove that.

Comment: I like approach 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with conditional parsing, I suggest you can use the common class with multiple attributes with optional value and used it according to requirement.  Please refer below code.

For example if `itemTitle` is `nil` then execute logic of `locationName` so on.

```
class Collection: NSObject, Codable {
    let collectionType: String
    let collectionName: String
    let data:data?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case collectionType
        case collectionName
    }
}

class data: NSObject, Codable {

    let itemTitle: String?
    let itemSubtitle: String?
    let locationName: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case itemTitle
        case itemSubtitle
        case locationName
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for us. Item and Location have a loooot of properties. I have to separate them, otherwise, it will be a huge salad.